# Spring JDBCTemplate update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I want to update multiple rows using JDBCTemplate with fix values using only one statement. My function gets a List of ids, and I uses Guava's Joiner to concatenate them into one string. When I try to call the JDBCTemplate's update function, using the joined ids as a parameter, it only updates the first element, as if somehow, somewhere, a "Limit 1" is being injected in the final query.

```
private int increase(final List<Long> ids){
    String query = "UPDATE mytable" +
                   "   SET count = count + 1," +
                   "       last_modified = NOW()" +
                   " WHERE id IN ( ? )";
    Object[] args = {Joiner.on(",").join(ids)};
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query, args);
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code? Am I using the wrong method? Is it a bug in the library? Should I just concatenate the ids in the query, and not send them as an argument?

Answer (score 3):

The following is the way to do that in Spring.

**Using JdbcTemplate**

> *batchUpdate(String sql, BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss)*

```
private void increase(List<Long> ids){
   String query = "UPDATE mytable" +
               "   SET count = count + 1," +
               "       last_modified = NOW()" +
               " WHERE id = ?";
     getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(query,new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                ps.setLong(1, ids.get(i));  
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return ids.size();
            }
        });

}
```

Check [this post](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/spring-jdbc-batch-update/) and see if it makes things clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the API has changed since you posted this question, but as of current writing, you don't need to use `batchUpdate`. The `update` method you're using works just fine.

The problem I see with your code snippet is this:

```
Object[] args = {Joiner.on(",").join(ids)};
```

There is no need to do that - what you've done is you've created a string containing commas as a single id, rather than a list of multiple ids. You've actually overcomplicated it, and all you need is:

```
private int increase(final List<Long> ids){
    String query = "UPDATE mytable" +
                   "   SET count = count + 1," +
                   "       last_modified = NOW()" +
                   " WHERE id IN ( ? )";
    Object[] args = { ids };
    return jdbcTemplate.update(query, args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any other libraries to pass list to Jdbctemplate.
It can be done easily by following way:

Create an object of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, then simply use

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("ids", ids);
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, parameters);
```

Slight modification in query after IN change to (:ids) instead of ? like

> String query = "UPDATE mytable" +
> "   SET count = count + 1," +
> "       last_modified = NOW()" +
> " WHERE id IN ( :ids )";